# How to run bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Hello I want to see all the messages in my topic I can do it in the console by running

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test  --from-beginning
```

I have Spring-kafka 2.6 dependency would appreciate the help thanks

Comment: Read the [Boot reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka) and the [spring-kafka reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#receiving-messages). Come back here with a more specific question if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell I have read the documentation and was able to solve my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to define bean

```
    private final KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer;
```

and then inside your method

```
   try {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(TIMEOUT);
    } finally {
            consumer.unsubscribe();
       
    }
```